# Nuxt head method not working while generating

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, meta-tags

I created a website with nuxt. It's working nicely except one issue. I have `head()` method in my page. It's able to updated meta in client side. But when I want to `generate` my website, I can't see the meta tags in generated html files. If you help me I'll be appreciated.

nuxt.config.js

```
mode: 'universal',
target: 'static',
```

about.vue

```
data() {
  return() {
    meta: { title: 'About Us' }
  }
}
head() {
  return {
    title: this.meta.title,
  }
},
```

My expectation is to see `About Us` title inside generated html file meta title.

Edit:
I checked generated files and I see `data-n-head="ssr"` doesn't exist in html codes. Why it's happening I'm not sure.